# what is the difference between active and reactive power?

Tags: electricity, electrical

What is active and reactive power ?
does the active power means power flows from source to load and reactive power as its vice-versa?

Comment: Have you read the Wiki for AC Power?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power

Answer (score 0):

Active power is a continuous AC electrical energy that is converted by the load to heat, light, mechanical work, battery charge or otherwise "consumed." Reactive power is AC electrical energy that continuously flows back and forth between the source and load. During a portion of each half cycle, the energy is stored in the source and load.